# Responsive Table with Vue and Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, vue.js, responsive

Im attempting to implement the following [Flexbox table](https://hashnode.com/post/really-responsive-tables-using-css3-flexbox-cijzbxd8n00pwvm53sl4l42cx) from Vasan Subramanian with vue.
That table is built manually, but That doesnt give much help when trying to make a component of it.
So Im willing to make it dinamically. and my first obstacle is to group each pair of two rows inside one div. Like the following

```
<div class="Table">

    <div class="Table-row Table-header">

            <div class="Table-row-item" v-for="key in cols" v-bind:style="{'flex-basis':basis, 'flex-grow':key.grow}">
                <a @click="sortBy(key)">{{key.title}}&nbsp;<i v-if="key.sortField==sort" class="{{reverse==1?'fa fa-sort-desc':'fa fa-sort-asc'}}" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>

    </div>
```

The previous code gives the normal table header

```
    <div class="Table-row-item">
        firstname
   </div>

    <div class="Table-row-item">
        lastname
   </div>

    <div class="Table-row-item">
        email
   </div>

    <div class="Table-row-item">
        company
   </div>
```

Im trying to achieve the following:

```
<div class=divider>  

   <div class="Table-row-item">
       firstname
   </div>

   <div class="Table-row-item">
       lastname
   </div>

</div>

<div class=divider>

   <div class="Table-row-item">
       email
   </div>

   <div class="Table-row-item">
       company
   </div> 

</div>
```

My Issue is I dont know how to represent that in code.
Any help would be very appreciated. I couldnt find any good examples about responsive tables with Flexbox. just the previous and this other from [Jonathan Lehman](http://inlehmansterms.net/2014/10/11/responsive-tables-with-flexbox/) An excellent Lecture using Sass.

Comment: If you want tables chances are you should use table elements and restyle them to flex. This is just going to sound like a mess to people using a screen reader. However, instead of manually inserting the divider why don't you style the columns by `:nth-child`?

Comment: @BillCriswell. thanks, did you read the Article I linked at the begining?. My goal is just make that Table Dinamically and with vue. Also. You could give ideas when using the :nth-child

Comment: hi, would you share your complete working Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to group your columns, and then loop over the columns within each group. Use a computed to do the grouping. Your `grow` specification doesn't quite fit this model; it seems like you want to have one grow spec per group, but I don't know exactly what the goal is there.

This code makes column groups of whatever size you choose and puts them in your dividers.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '.Table',
  data: {
    columns: ['firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'company'].map((n) => ({
      title: n,
      sortField: n
    })),
    perDivider: 2,
    basis: '50%',
    grow: 1,
    sort: null
  },
  computed: {
    colGroups: function() {
      return this.by(this.perDivider, this.columns);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    by: function(n, arr) {
      const result = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += n) {
        result.push(arr.slice(i, i + n));
      }
      return result;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div class="Table">
  Table here
  <div class="Table-row Table-header">

    <div class="Table-row-item" v-for="colGroup in colGroups" v-bind:style="{'flex-basis':basis, 'flex-grow':grow}">
      <a v-for="key in colGroup" @click="sortBy(key)">
        {{key.title}}&nbsp;<i v-if="key.sortField==sort" class="{{reverse==1?'fa fa-sort-desc':'fa fa-sort-asc'}}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ Roy J  thanks, It is always very refreshing to Study new code, and yours seems very clean. I will accept your answer as valid saying mine is also working. Thank you once again to take the time and help. If you have read the post made by Vasan Subramanian the next step is to make groups of 4. I defenetely think this Thread will encourage people to make this kind of table.

Comment: Grow is set because I will have an "option" field which should be smaller. Also there is the Published field for  Publishing posts. In relation to those field sizes, the other Fields which we would call Data, should be bigger than those.

Answer (score 0):

I Started with a computed property

```
odd(){
                var numberOdds = 0;
                var arr = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < this.cols.length; i++) {
                    if (i % 2 == 0) {
                        numberOdds++;
                    }
                }
                var j=0;
                for (i=0;i<numberOdds;i++){
                    this.arr[i]=j;
                    j+=2;
                }
                return numberOdds;
            }
```

so..

```
<div class="Table">
        <div class="Table-row Table-header">

            <div class="divider" v-for="number in odd">

              {{cols[arr[number]].title}}
              {{cols[arr[number]+1].title}}
            </div>

        </div>
   <div class="Table-row" v-for="item in items.data" >

        <div class="divider" v-for="number in odd">

            <div class="Table-row-item">
                {{item[cols[arr[number]].name]}}
            </div>
            <div class="Table-row-item">
                {{item[cols[arr[number]+1].name]}}
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

This works. testing purposes